# yo aspnet generator not detected

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator, ubuntu-15.04

I am using ubuntu vivid. Trying to use yeoman aspnet generator. Installed the generators using below commands

> sudo npm install -g yo
>
> sudo npm install -g generator-aspnet

When i try using it using the command : yo aspnet
i get the below error

```
Error aspnet 

You don't seem to have a generator with the name aspnet installed. You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then >install them with npm install [name]. To see the 0 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.
```

I am able to see the generator files under `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-aspnet`
What am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

For any Yeoman issues, always run `yo doctor`.